# aftersave doesn't work in yii

Tags: date, datetime, yii

aftersave doesnt work in yii ....... here i go after i create a record in tbl1 i need to update the expiry date in tbl1 ie., done by adding tbl2 duration  following is the code

```
parent::afterSave();
    if ($this->isNewRecord)
    {
        $sql1="select sid,createdate 
        from tbl1
        where(pid=". $_GET['ppid'] ." and mpid=". $this->mid. ")";
        $edata=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql1)->queryRow();


        var_dump($edata);
        $sql2="select duration
        from tbl2
        where ( pid=". $_GET['ppid'] ." and sid=".$edata['sid'].")";

$duration=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql2)->queryScalar();

        var_dump($duration);
    //  $expirydate=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($edate['createdate']."+ $duration"));
    $expirydate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($edata['createdate'] . " + $duration "));
        var_dump($expirydate);
        $sql="update tbl1 set expirydate=".$expirydate." where ( mpid=" .$this->mid ." and pid=".      $_GET['ppid'].")";
             $connection=Yii::app()->db;
                $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
                      $tts=$command->execute();
```

The error i get is

```
  CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00 where ( mid=42 and prid=4)' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: update tbl1 set expirydate=1970-01-01 00:00:00 where ( mid=42 and pid=4)
```

Comment: Why not just make a model class for whatever tbl1 is? That way you can limit the code to a $tbl1 = Tbl1::model()->findByAttributes(array('pid' => ..., 'mpid' => ...)); $tbl1->expirydate = ...; $tbl1->save(); -- Much cleaner

Comment: i do have model class for tbl1 the thing is i got to update it after the record is saved and the duration to be added is in another tbl2       $expirydate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($edata['createdate'] . " + $duration ")); its not fetching the $edata['createdate'] nor $duration  am not understanding why is it so

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand that, but just call the ->refresh() method on your activerecord instance to reload the row from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
"update tbl1 set expirydate='".$expirydate."' where
```

You need to keep your expiry date inside single quotes

Note:-I have added a `'` before your `".$expirydate` and after `$expirydate."`

#### Update

Try the following change

```
$expirydate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$edata['createdate'] + $duration "));
```

Comment: it stores 1970-01-01 00:00:00 as expiry date i got to store  $expirydate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($edata['createdate'] . " + $duration "));

Comment: doing so i get the following error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in

Comment: can you post the values of your $edata['createdate'] and $duration ?

Comment: i think its not fetching the $edata['createdate'] nor $duration am not understanding why is it so hv var_dump it but due to aftersave i cant see those value ...